# I just want a percent sign at end of my edittext like in google

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to use imageview but was of no help I would prefer that of this pic

Like the mic button
[image]
I don't want to set an onClick for It

Comment: pls show your xml , if so we can help you

Comment: first yu should post your xml code what yu tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

put your image in

```
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

or you can do like this

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pwdLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/emailLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textinputlayoutpwd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signinpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginpwdicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lock_icon2"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

I used here **icon image** in textview. you can use here image view, image button or any other layout as for your requirements.

Comment: feel free to ask if yu've any prob